# Javascript object construction without "this"

Tags: javascript, object, this

In order to get to the next level of JavaScript Wizardy I need to understand object creation a bit better. (I'm an artist trapped in the Dungeons of Code)!

I know that an object can me created with a function like this:

```
function Dinosaur(name, carnivore, era, weight)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.diet = carnivore;
  this.year = era;
  this.weight = weight;
}
```

However, I am also aware that there can be a lot of confusion with the keyword "this". Since there are various ways to create objects within Javascript, is it possible to write the above function (simply) without using "this"? Thank you.

Comment: Depends on whether you want to use advanced things like `prototype` or simply create an object. If you just want to create an object, `return {'name': name, 'diet' : carnivore, ... }` would be the most simple way. Note that you would call it as `var trex = Dinosaur('Rex','HellYes', ...);`, don't use `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
function Dinosaur(name, carnivore, era, weight)
{
    var obj = {

        name: name,
        diet: carnivore,
        year: era,
        weight: weight
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: oh, someone had exact the same solution ^^ in my case i also show how to create the object :) function call is myObj = Dinosaur(...);

Answer (score 2):

You can simply return an object from the function.

```
function Dinosaur(name, carnivore, era, weight)
{
  return {
    name: name,
    diet: carnivore,
    year: era,
    weight: weight
  };
}
```

And you need to create objects without `new` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Of course :-)

You can always use some **private** variables, then make some getters:

```
var Dinosaur = (function(){

    function Dinosaur(name, carnivore, era, weight) {
      var obj = {
           name: name,
           diet: carnivore,
           year: era,
           weight: weight
      };
      this.get = function(name) { return obj[name]; };
    }


    Dinosaur.prototype = {
        get name(){
            return this.get("name");
        },
        get diet(){
            return this.get("diet");
        },
        get year(){
            return this.get("year");
        },
        get weight(){
            return this.get("weight");
        }
    };

    return Dinosaur;
})();
```

Now you can do:

```
var d = new Dinosaur('al', 'yes', '123', 123)
//then 
console.log(d.diet); // logs "yes"
```

But if you try:

```
d.diet = "something new";
console.log(d.diet); //still logs "yes"
```

So if you wanted to **actually** set these values you would have to add setters to the prototype:

```
...
set diet(val){
    //some function to set diet
},
...
```

Then this all just gets confusing....

Comment: What would happen if I create two instances? e.g. `var d = new Dinosaur('al', 'yes', '123', 123); var e = new Dinosaur('foo', 'no', '42', 1337)` and then call `d.name`? :)

Comment: Hmmmm weird... Why does it do that @C5H8NNaO4 They should be completely separate...

Comment: I fixed it @C5H8NNaO4 Have fun!

Comment: Yea I **know** I used `this`, but not in the OP's context